# AngularJS SELECT doesn't validate properly

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs, validation

This is an AngularJS application (1.2.16). I browse to a dialog to edit some item. One of the controls is a multi-`SELECT` with the following visible values:

```
incident
work order
```

These visible values correspond to the following data values:

```
INCIDENT
WORK_ORDER
```

This is done through using the `ng-options=" ... as ... for ... in ... "` pattern, using an enumeration:

```
var FlexFieldSubjectTypeEnum = {
    INCIDENT:{name:"INCIDENT", description:"incident"},
    WORK_ORDER:{name:"WORK_ORDER", description:"work order"}
}
```

If have a form pretty much as follows:

```
<form ng-submit="save(formName)" name="formName" class="form-horizontal">

  ...

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Subject type:</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select name="subjectType"
                ng-options="type.name as type.description for type in getEnumAsArray('FlexFieldSubjectTypeEnum') | orderBy:'name'"
                ng-model="entity.subjectType"
                required></select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now, if the dialog loads the item (`$scope.entity`) from the backend and `entity.subjectType` is set to the first item in the list, the form validation marks it as unset. I have many other dialogs with similar constructs and have not seen this problem anywhere else.

> [image]

If the item returned from the backend points to the second item (`WORK_ORDER`), this is nicely represented in the `SELECT` ("`work order`") and there is no validation error.

The problem does exist equally when using `required` or `ng-required="true"`.

The problem does not exist if I remove the `required` attribute, but then the field also suddenly becomes optional, which is not what I wanted.

Your help much appreciated!

Comment: is your use of `ng=options` just a typo here? or is that actually how you have it in your code?

Comment: It was a typo indeed, I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost a month later, with meanwhile an upgrade from Bootstrap v2.2.2 to v3.1.1 the problem disappeared.